# Caffeine not working with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

Previously I installed caffeine with the following steps and it worked fine:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install caffeine
```

But recently I had a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04 and having trouble with caffeine. It installs nicely. But not running. Terminal is showing the following error messages:

```
╔═[shoumma dell-3442 : ~ ]   
╚══╣$║ caffeine

(caffeine:7898): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:3398:10: 'filter' is not a valid property name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/caffeine", line 36, in <module>
    ewmh = EWMH()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ewmh.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.display = _display or display.Display()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 62, in __init__
    display.Display.__init__(*(self, ) + args, **keys)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 129, in __init__
    raise error.DisplayConnectionError(self.display_name, r.reason)
Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError: Can't connect to display ":0": b'No protocol specified\n'
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Am I the only one who is facing this trouble? Please let me know if there is any fix for this issue. I love this software. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unity or GNOME?

Comment: @A.B. I am using Unity.